# Combine 2 Lists, List<Expression<Func>> with OR between them and OR/AND between items

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, expression

I have 2 lists

```
List<Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>>> andConditions = new List<Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>>>();

List<Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>>> orConditions = new List<Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>>>();
```

The first one, I'd like AND between each items, the second one OR between each items. At the end, I'd like combine the 2 lists with a OR between.

Example of result:

```
exprList1 AND exprList1 OR exprList2 OR exprList2 OR exprList2
```

Could you tell me about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`PredicateBuilder`](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit#predicatebuilder) from [`LINQKit`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit) nuget package.

> Of all the things that will drive you to manually constructing expression trees, the need for dynamic predicates is the most common in a typical business application. Fortunately, it’s possible to write a set of simple and reusable extension methods that radically simplify this task. This is the role of our PredicateBuilder class.

First install nuget package:

```
Install-Package LinqKit
```

After that you can use `PredicateBuilder` to combine expressions. Long version:

```
// AND
var combinedAnd = PredicateBuilder.New<MyClass>(true);
foreach (var andCondition in andConditions)
{
    combinedAnd = combinedAnd.And(andCondition);
}

// OR
var combinedOr = PredicateBuilder.New<MyClass>(false);
foreach (var orCondition in orConditions)
{
    combinedOr = combinedOr.Or(orCondition);
}

var finalExpression = combinedAnd.Or(combinedOr);
```

Short LINQ based version:

```
var combinedAnd = andConditions
    .Aggregate(
        PredicateBuilder.New<MyClass>(true), 
        (current, andCondition) => current.And(andCondition));
var combinedOr = orConditions
    .Aggregate(
        PredicateBuilder.New<MyClass>(false), 
        (current, orCondition) => current.Or(orCondition));
var finalExpression = combinedAnd.Or(combinedOr);
```

`PredicateBuilder.New<MyClass>(true)` returns an initial predicate that returns `true`. It's suitable behavior to combine predicates with AND operatation because it will create `true && predicate_1 && ... && predicate_n` result. `PredicateBuilder.New<MyClass>(false)` is suitable for OR operation.

If you can't use external libraries you can implement methods to combine expressions yourself:

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        var body = Expression.And(
            Expression.Invoke(expr1, parameter),
            Expression.Invoke(expr2, parameter)
        );
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        var body = Expression.Or(
            Expression.Invoke(expr1, parameter),
            Expression.Invoke(expr2, parameter)
        );
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
    }
}
```

And use it in your code:

```
var combinedAnd = andConditions.Aggregate((expr1, expr2) => expr1.And(expr2));
var combinedOr = orConditions.Aggregate((expr1, expr2) => expr1.Or(expr2));
var finalExpression = combinedAnd.Or(combinedOr);
```